Tossing cookies and internet browsing history
What is the route to delete internet (not You Tube) browsing history and cookies? I could find it in previous Ubuntu but not in the latest one just uploaded. Looked everywhere I could think of. Need to dump Hx and cookies due to older processor capacity.

What browser are you using ?

I'm not sure what you're asking, as most browsers have their own storage methods for such details, and that is not related to package management you tagged. Please be specific with details (including what Ubuntu product/release you're using, as you don't specify & that has influence on where files are located; ie. if browser is snap or deb packaged)

There is no global Ubuntu setting or storage for cookies and browsing history. Those are controlled by whatever browser application you choose to use.
Check your browser settings.
